# Solving system of equations with prime numbers.

Tags: prime-numbers, systems-of-equations

Let $p_{1}>p_{2}>p_{3}>p_{4}>p_{5}$ are prime numbers smaller than natural $x$

> Find the smallest ( in respect to $x$) solution of the system of equations:
>   $$\begin{cases} 2x-p_{4}=p_{5}^{a_{1}}\\2x-p_{2}=p_{4}^{a_{2}}\\2x-p_{1}=p_{4}^{a_{3}}p_{5}^{a_{4}}\\2x-p_{3}=p_{1}^{a_{5}}\\2x-p_{5}=p_{3}^{a_{6}}\end{cases}$$
>   Where $a_{i}$ is natural number for each $i$

So far i tried to write down c++ program but it does not work.

Thanks for help.

Comment: With the degree of flexibility you have in terms of the powers involved, plus that the primes are just distinct & in a certain order, I highly doubt you can find any algebraic type solution, or even very much in the way of simplifications or tests you can do. For a given set of primes, you can do certain modulo tests, but I don't know of anything else much you can try.

Comment: are the exponents also ordered ? I can easily show x>13 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution:

First note, you can order by magnitude on the left hand side:
$$\begin{cases}2x-p_5=p_3^{a_6}\\2x-p_4=p_5^{a_1}\\2x-p_3=p_1^{a_5}\\2x-p_2=p_4^{a_2}\\2x-p_1=p_4^{a_3}p_5^{a_4}\end{cases}$$

Second note, all left hand sides are greater than x, this means every right hand side has at least 1 exponent greater than 1.

Third note, no p values are 2 by distributivity of multiplication over subtraction, and our strict ordering.

Fourth note, Subtracting left hand sides bottom to top gives us differences of values (potentially minimum if guessed correctly)

From all this we can gather the following

$$\begin{eqnarray}x>p_1>p_2>p_3>p_4>p_5>2\\2p_5\mid p_4+p_3^{a_6}\\2p_4\mid p_1-p_2\\2p_3\mid p_1^{a_5}+p_5\\2p_1\mid p_4^{a_3}p_5^{a_4}+p_3\\2p_5\mid p_1-p_4\\2p_5\mid p_1+p_3^{a_6}\\2p_4\mid p_2+p_5^{a_1}\\2p_4\mid p_1+p_5^{a_1}\\\end{eqnarray}$$

There are more restrictions, but no solution to my knowledge.